# Why my AT command echo in my GSM modem?

Tags: c++, gsm, at-command

I have a GSM modem and test it by putty. it works. Then I send AT with my c++ program, but modem replies AT. It just echoes my command and no answer OK.
this is my code :

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <iostream>
int fd;
int openport(void)
{

fd=open("/dev/ttyUSB0",O_RDWR|O_NOCTTY|O_NDELAY);

        if (fd==-1)
                {
                perror("open_port: unable to open port /dev/ttyUSB0\n");
                return -1;
                }
        else
                {
                printf("open_port: succesfully open port /dev/ttyUSB0\n");
                fcntl(fd,F_SETFL,0);
                return 1;
                }
}
void closeport(void)
{
    close(fd);
}
void configport(void)
{
struct termios options;
tcgetattr(fd,&options);
cfsetispeed(&options,B9600);
cfsetospeed(&options,B9600);
options.c_cflag |=  (CLOCAL | CREAD);
tcsetattr(fd,TCSANOW,&options);
options.c_cflag &= ~CSIZE;
options.c_cflag |= CS8;
options.c_cflag &= ~ PARENB;
options.c_cflag &= ~CSTOPB;
options.c_cflag &= ~CSIZE;
options.c_cflag |= CS8;
options.c_iflag &= ~(IXON|IXOFF|IXANY);
}
void writeport1(void)
{
    char w[]="AT\r\n";

    //std::cout << strlen(w);
    //std::cout << w;

    write(fd,w,sizeof(w));
}



int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    int aa ;
    char i[10];
    aa=openport();
    if (aa==1)
    {
        configport();
        writeport1();
        printf("start reading ..... \n");
        aa=read(fd,i,sizeof(i));
        i[aa]=0;//terminate the string
        //std::cout << i << std::endl;
        printf("finish reading ..... \n");

    }

    closeport();
    return a.exec();
}
```

the output is this :

> Go to open port open_port:
>   succesfully open port /dev/ttyUSB0 port
>   [root@FriendlyARM /]#./SerialPort -qws
>   open_port: succesfully open port /dev/ttyUSB0
>   start reading .....

where is my mistake?

Comment: It could be useful to find some tool that will allow you to see exactly the bytes that are travelling through the serial port. I have a hardware device I can put in-line with the serial cable and capture the data, and software exists that allows you to see the data as it passes through the serial port driver. Watching the *actual data on the line* can be immensely useful for troubleshooting things like this. It's likely you'll see the bytes coming from your program aren't quite what you expect, or that the "OK" is really coming back, just late like others suggest may be happening.

Comment: how can i see the byte transfer with serial port? I think this is my problem. ( I mean maybe that data i sent has a problem) . when I send AT with my pc to my modem its immediately answer OK.

Comment: It's a duplicate question from the same user: https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/25864958

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't terminated the string `w`, so while the `write` call is fine, you get undefined behaviour when you pass it to `cout` - change:

```
char w[4];
w[0]=65;
w[1]=84;
w[2]=13;
w[3]=10;
//sprintf(i,"2f9",k);
std::cout << w;
write(fd1,w,sizeof(w));
```

to:

```
char w[5];
w[0]='A';
w[1]='T';
w[2]=13;
w[3]=10;
w[4]=0;                  // <<<
//sprintf(i,"2f9",k);
std::cout << w;
write(fd1,w,strlen(w));  // <<<
```

or perhaps more succinctly:

```
char w[] = "AT\r\n"
std::cout << w;
write(fd1,w,strlen(w));
```

Comment: thank my friend. but after changing the code. it still not work  :(

Comment: You probably have more than one bug, but at least this fixes one of them. Note that most modems echo commands by default, so if you send "AT" you'll get the "AT" echoed back, followed by "OK".

Comment: Echoing commands can confuse the console, so turn off command echoing.
The AT command is ATE0. then the echo turned off

Answer (score 2):

By Default GSM module returns the same "**AT**" commands which are echo in GSM modem. So you can switch off echo by sending the command "**ATE0**" and Save the setting to permanent memory by sending the command "**AT&W**",  followed by "OK".
You can re-enable the echo again by sending command "**ATE1**" if you want it once again.

Comment: I'd generalize the answer. The most (if not all) terminals do echoing before answering. This way you can control that the command you sent was recieved (think of very remote termanal with unstable connection). The echo can be suppressed either on the remote side (by sending a proper command - see the manual of your device) or on the local side. At last you can ignore the echo by skipping the same number of bytes you've just sent.

Answer (score 0):

It takes time for the modem to reply `OK`, try to wait for some time and then read, or put the read in a loop.

Comment: when i test in putty , the modem reply me immediately OK. i put sleep(5),but nothing change.