# How to received data from the serial port?

Tags: c++, linux, serial-port

I wrote code to send messages via serial port and receive them. Unfortunately, when receiving a message, I see that it contains a sent message, "\n", "\0" received message.

```
char port_name[] = "/dev/ttyUSB0";

    int port = open(port_name, O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY);
    if(port < 0){
        fprintf(stderr, "Error opening: %s\n", strerror(errno));
    }
    struct termios settings;
    memset(&settings, 0, sizeof(settings));

    tcgetattr(port, &settings);

    cfsetispeed(&settings, B115200);
    cfsetospeed(&settings, B115200);

    settings.c_cflag &= ~PARENB;
    settings.c_cflag &= ~CSTOPB;
    settings.c_cflag &= ~CSIZE;
    settings.c_cflag |= CS8;
    settings.c_lflag &= ~(ECHO | ECHONL | ICANON | IEXTEN | ISIG);
    settings.c_cflag &= ~CRTSCTS; 
    settings.c_cflag |= (CLOCAL | CREAD);
    settings.c_cc[VMIN] = 0;
    settings.c_cc[VTIME] = 10;

    tcflush(port, TCIFLUSH);
    int er = tcsetattr(port, TCSANOW, &settings);
    if(er < 0){
        fprintf(stderr, "Error set: %s\n", strerror(errno));
    }

    char* str = "AT\n";

    std::cout << "Sending:" << std::endl;

    int res = write(port, str, strlen(str));
    if(res < 0){
        std::cout << "Did not send" << std::endl;
        return;
    }
    sleep(1);

    std::cout << "Receiving:" << std::endl;
    char buffer[20];
    memset(&buffer, '\0', sizeof(buffer));

    int n = read(port, &buffer, sizeof(buffer));
    if(n < 0){
        fprintf(stderr, "Error reading: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        return;
    }

    printf("Read %i bytes. Reseived message: %s\n", n, buffer);

    close(port);
```

My output:

```
Read 11 bytes. Reseived message: AT



OK
```

But I want get single "OK". How could I fix that? When I add lines

```
settings.c_iflag &= ~(IXON | IXOFF | IXANY);
settings.c_iflag &= ~(IGNBRK|BRKINT|PARMRK|ISTRIP|INLCR|IGNCR|ICRNL);
```

The output has changed to:

```
Read 9 bytes. Reseived message: AT
OK
```

Between AT and OK I have signs like "\n" nad "\0"

Comment: If your program communicates with a modem, the modem may echo the commands back. You might have to disable this. See commands `ATE0` and maybe `AT&W` and https://stackoverflow.com/a/61225090/10622916

Comment: You might also want to turn off OPOST.

Comment: When I sent the same message via putty, the modem replied with a single "OK"